# Override "dbo" schema name in EntityFramework Code First Migrations

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to create an schema independent model with EntityFramework Codefirst and an Oracle database but EF uses as defaults for migrations dbo as schema.
I overridden OnModelCreating method on my DBContext to solve this and use the user in the connectionString instead

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(string.Empty);
}
```

The problem is that __MigrationHistory ignores this default schema and I get this error when running first migration:

> ORA-01918: User 'dbo' does not exist

Tried [this msdn entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456841(v=vs.113).aspx) to customize the schema for this table.

CustomHistoryContext:

```
public class CustomHistoryContext : HistoryContext
{
    public CustomHistoryContext(DbConnection dbConnection, string defaultSchema)
            : base(dbConnection, defaultSchema) {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(String.Empty);
    }
}
```

And DBConfiguration:

```
public sealed class Configuration :
        DbMigrationsConfiguration<Model.MyDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        SetHistoryContextFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client",
                                 (connection, defaultSchema) => new CustomHistoryContext(connection, defaultSchema));
    }

    protected override void Seed(Model.Model1 context)
    {
    }
}
```

And is working fine for the first migration. But when I modify my entity model and try to reflect this change with `add-migration` command I get the following error:

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following
>   explicit migrations are pending: [201706281804589_initial,
>   201706281810218_pp2]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before
>   attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

Looks like EF gets lost and can't find migrations history at this point.

When I comment the `SetHistoryContextFactory` instruction in `Configuration` it works for subsequent `add-migration` commands but this workaround isn't enough for scenarios when I want to run all migrations from scratch like deploying.

Does anyone knows if I'm in the good way to accomplish this or if there is a better workaround for this?

Comment: Which Oracle provider are you using?  It might be a problem with the Oracle provider not implementing this feature.  If you have quick access to it, maybe try this out with SQL Server quick and see if the results are the same?  Also, not sure if giving a string.Empty schema makes it default to the embedded default (dbo).

Comment: Hi @MichaelWeinand and thanks for the quick comment. Im using **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework v12.1.2400** from Nuget package. Tried with SQL Server but and `string.Empty` for `MyDBcontext` schema name and sql script is ok but for `CustomHistoryContext` the generated sql to insert the first migration in history is: `INSERT [CodeFirstDatabase].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])...` note the CodeFirstDatabase schema name

Comment: Unfortunately SQL Server and Oracle have slightly different concepts around what a schema is and how to interact with it.  I'm guessing that [CodeFirstDatabase] name is a built-in default that gets used if you pass in string.Empty.  What are you actually trying to set it to?  Even in Oracle I'm not sure if you can truly not provide a schema name?

Comment: A simplified tutorial can be found here: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/CodeFirst/index.html#

Comment: @oskr Hey, I have the same problem. Did the below answer fix it for you or did you find another solution - cheers

Answer (score 1):

Go to Migrations -> Configuration.cs and below mentioned code. This fix worked for me!

```
class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CodeFirstOracleProject.Context>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        var historyContextFactory = GetHistoryContextFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client");
        SetHistoryContextFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client",
                                 (dbc, schema) => historyContextFactory.Invoke(dbc, "YourSchemaName"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try runnig **Enable-Migrations -force** again. Then run **Add-Migration SomeDescription –IgnoreChanges**. After that, run "**Update-Database - Verbose**". This worked to me

Answer (score 0):

I successfully tried the following inside the `Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration` class for Oracle, in order to change the history schema to "Test":

```
var historyContextFactory = GetHistoryContextFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client");
SetHistoryContextFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client",
                         (dbc, schema) => historyContextFactory.Invoke(dbc, "Test"));
```

So basically, instead of trying to register a custom history context with unchanged default schema, I tried to register the default history context with **changed default schema**.

The result: when I run `Update-Database -Script`, the resulting script contains the new schema for creation of the `__MigrationHistory` table as well as for inserting the new history values:

```
create table "Test"."__MigrationHistory"
    -- ...

insert into "Test"."__MigrationHistory"("MigrationId", "ContextKey", "Model", "ProductVersion") ...
```

However, lets be perfectly clear: I just tried what I expected to work by intuition and it did work for me. I didn't find any reliable documentation to support this solution.

Answer (score 0):

open Migrations -> Configuration.cs and add

```
 public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;            
        var historyContextFactory = GetHistoryContextFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client");
        SetHistoryContextFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client",
                                 (dbc, schema) => historyContextFactory.Invoke(dbc, "your_schema_name_hear"));

    }
```